# Testing a method that delegates to another object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

This is a model in my project -

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  def active?
    SubscriptionValidationPolicy.new(self).active?
  end
end
```

When I'm unit testing `active?`, should I setup a `subscription` for active and inactive states and assert on that or should I make a double for `SubscriptionValidationPolicy`, inject it in somehow and then assert whether `active?` was called on it?

Or is it all just opinionated how I go about testing this. I'm going to be testing `SubscriptionValidationPolicy` anyway, so it feels redundant to do a "state based" test for the `Subscription#active?` method.

Would love some thoughts on this :)

Comment: If you test the policy anyway than I would use a double, but that is primarily opinion-based...

Comment: I wouldn’t even bother testing that method as-is. It’s a one-liner that does simple delegation and doesn’t have any conditional logic. Then again, I would also say that your model shouldn’t have delegations to business logic like this at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @spickermann I would setup a test as follows:

```
#spec/models/subscription_spec.rb
#
describe Subscription do 

  let(:subscription) { Subscription.new }
  context '#active? delegation' do 
    let(:policy) {spy('subscription_validation_policy')}
    before :each do 
      allow(SubscriptionValidationPolicy).to receive(:new).and_return(policy)
      subscription.active?
    end

    it 'instantiates a SubscriptionValidationPolicy with self' do 
      expect(SubscriptionValidationPolicy).to have_received(:new).with(subscription)
    end
    it 'calls SubscriptionValidationPolicy#active?' do 
      expect(policy).to have_received(:active?)
    end
  end
end
```

Then actually test `SubscriptionValidationPolicy#active?` for the logical considerations in the spec for `SubscriptionValidationPolicy`.

Comment: For a bump in readability; the first _it_ block could be changed to:    
    `subscription.active?  
    expect(SubscriptionValidationPolicy).to have_received(:new).with(subscription)`  
Just because I like the _arrange-act-assert_ (_given-when-then_) pattern :D

Comment: @seanriordan08 updated due to the fact that it does make for a cleaner refactor in which the call can be moved to the before block as well

Comment: Nice. Thanks so much folks. very helpful